# How do I author Adobe Flash movies?

Tags: flash

Is there a decent GUI for building Flash movies in Ubuntu? An easy-to-use API would be fine, too. I did find [Ming](http://www.libming.org/) (API for creating .swf files) and am going to check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Gimp](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gimp) with [swf plugin](http://my.opera.com/area42/blog/flash-swf-export-for-gimp).

Download the plugin to your folder ~/.gimp-2.6/plug-ins and mark it as executable.

The install `libjpeg62-dev` `libfreetype6-dev` `zlib1g-dev` from repositories and swtools from [here](http://www.swftools.org/download.html).

Or if you're lazy, just paste this on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp libjpeg62-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev && cd ~/.gimp-2.6/plug-ins && wget -c http://files.myopera.com/area42/files/flash-swf-export.py && chmod +x ~/.gimp-2.6/plug-ins/flash-swf-export.py && cd ~/Downloads && wget -c http://www.swftools.org/swftools-0.9.1.tar.gz && tar -xf swftools-0.9.1.tar.gz && cd ~/Downloads/swftools-0.9.1/ && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

The go to "File" > "Flash SWF Export"

[image]

Comment: Nice! Does it work for you, though? I can't get this to actually output a .swf file on Ubuntu 11.04, Gimp 2.6.11. It appears to be doing the work of exporting to swf, but no file exists on disk after the progress bars complete and the dialog closes.

FYI, I also had to `chmod 755 flash-swf-export`. I also renamed it (removing the .py extension), but I'm not sure if that's actually necessary.

Comment: Yes I'm having the same problem here :-( I'm investigating...

Comment: Fixed! We need swtools. Enjoy!

Comment: Installing swftools made it work for me too, thanks! The command line was helpful to know which development libraries I had to install to build swftools.

Comment: Anyone tested this and does mind to provide a sample of the results of your tests? I have seen in the link provided in the answer (http://my.opera.com/area42/blog/flash-swf-export-for-gimp) that people (including the comments of Eckhard M. Jägerarea) reads "At the moment the script do just convert an image into an SWF. This is sometimes useful for saving file size (instead of an PNG24) and getting alpha values too (when embedding Flash with wmode transparent). The next version will include animation support [...]" Is animation already possible? I would love to see any animation example.

Comment: The animation is possible, I've done that but I don't have the file anymore. I will make another and then post a link for you ASAP.